# Help with Power Curve MCMC

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, markov-process, jags, power-law

I'm trying to analyze some $D$ non-logistic cumulative data in a time series, bounded below by 0 and unbounded above.
Splitting data into $W$ time windows of $d$ days, I know each window can be described by one of these four different growths:

- exponential
- linear
- logarithmic
- constant

Example of data:

```
require(RcppRoll)

rawData <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maxdevblock/covid-19-time-series/master/csv/COVID-Confirmed.csv")
countries <- levels(rawData$Country.Region)
# Choose a country
country <- "Tanzania"

y <- rawData[rawData$Country.Region == country,]
# Data from 1st day
y <- y[5:length(y)]
# Smooth data
y <- roll_mean(y, 7)
```

I thought to use a very simple power curve (Freundlich)

$y = \alpha \cdot x ^ \beta$

where $x = [1 ... d]$

that can describe all wanted growth types:

- $\beta = 0$, constant
- $0 < \beta < 1$, logarithmic
- $\beta = 1$, linear
- $\beta > 1$, exponential

Using `scipy` module `curve_fit` in python it correctly works but I want to do it bayesian with a Markov chain Monte Carlo in `R` to obtain $\beta$ params HDIs.

So I thought to use `JAGS` and:

- split $D$ data into $W$ time windows of $d$ days (I chose $d=14$), where each window starts from $t_0 \in \{D_0, D_1, D_2 ... D_{n-d}\}$
- let each window first element be 1 (subtracting the first window element to the vector and adding 1)
- calculate $\mathbb{E}[y]$ expected with the chosen power equation
- distribute observed $y$ in each time window as **Normal** with $\tau$ precision
- distribute $\alpha$ and $\beta$ params priors as **Uniform** within an expected range
- distribute $\tau$ as uninformative **Gamma**

```
model {
  for ( s in 1:Stot ) {
    alpha[s] ~ dunif( 0 , 2 )
    beta[s] ~ dunif( -1 , 10 )

    tau[s] ~ dgamma( 0.001 , 0.001 )
    sigma[s] <- 1 / sqrt( tau[s] )
    
    for ( t in s:(s + Ttot) ) {
      E[s,t] <- alpha[s] * (t - s + 1) ^ beta[s]
      y[s,t] ~ dnorm( E[s,t] , tau[s] )
    }
  }
}
```

Running `JAGS` with

```
n.chains=4 ,
adapt=100 ,
burnin=500 , 
sample=1000 ,
thin=1 ,
```

Even if $\beta$ params Means are correctly estimated, many windows show autocorrelation and/or very bad traces.

Results of $\beta$ param:
[image]

Example of very bad traces:
[image: Bad-acf]
[image: Bad-combo]

Example of "not too bad" (but maybe not optimal) traces:
[image]
[image]

What am I missing?

Any suggestions on how to fix/improve the MCMC?

Thank you!

Comment: I do not know JAGS well enough to know what your main problems are, but in Stan (you can also use that quite easily via rstan in R or pystan in Python) I'd suspect you'd want to work on the log-scale.

Comment: `thin=1` might be a great cause of the autocorrelation, because you save all samples. It's usually recommended to save only some $n$th sample. Increasing that heavily, e.g. to `thin=50`, and increasing burnin and the number of samples as well, may already resolve some parts of autocorrelation.

Comment: @Björn I'll try with `pystan`, have problems with `rstan` on Catalina (worst upgrade ever, I'm gonna downgrade soon)

Comment: @LuckyPal thanks, I tried increasing `thin=50`: works better if $0\leq\beta\leq1$ but the more $\beta$ increases above 1, the more autocorrelation and bad traces. I think there's something wrong with the model but I can't get what exactly...

Comment: Just another random shot: `dgamma( 0.001 , 0.001 )` might be _too uninformative_ for the MCMC algorithm to work smoothly. At least, that's a common issue with non-trivial models in `Stan`, which can be solved by changing it for example to `dgamma( 0.1 , 0.1 )` - of course, that might be too informative for your purposes.

Comment: @Björn I chose the Freundlich equation because $\alpha x ^ \beta = \alpha \exp(\log(x^\beta)) = \alpha \exp(\beta \log(x))$

Comment: @LuckyPal tried your suggestion, slightly better but the same autocorrelation occurs when $\beta >> 1$...

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution. Maybe not the best, but working...

Since I'm not interested in evaluating $\alpha$, but $\beta$ only, I did scale windows' data and days to a $[0..1]$ range

```
winDays <- 14

# Get and smooth data
y <- rawData[rawData$Country.Region == country,]
y <- y[5:length(y)]
y <- as.vector(t(y))
y <- roll_mean(y, 7)
  
Stot = length(y) - winDays
  
Y <- NULL

# Scale data to [0..1]
for(s in 1:Stot){
  yWin <- y[s:(s+winDays-1)]
  yWin <- yWin - yWin[1]
  if( yWin[winDays] != 0){
    yWin <- yWin / yWin[winDays]
  } else {
    # because x^0 = 1
    yWin <- rep(1.0, winDays)
  }
  yWin <- as.vector(yWin)
  Y <- rbind(Y, yWin)
}

# days range [0..1]
winRange <- seq(from=0, to=1, length.out=winDays)
```

and edited the model to

```
model {
  for ( s in 1:Stot ) {
    beta[s] ~ dunif( -1 , 10 )
    
    tau[s] ~ dgamma( 0.001 , 0.001 )
    sigma[s] <- 1 / sqrt( tau[s] )
    
    # start from 2 to avoid 0^0
    for ( t in 2:winDays ) {
      E[s,t] <- pow( winRange[t] , beta[s] )
      y[s,t] ~ dnorm( E[s,t] , tau[s] )
    }
  }
}
```

starting from the second element of each window to avoid evaluating the undefined $0^0$.

Now with only

```
n.chains=4 ,
adapt=250 ,
burnin=500 , 
sample=1000 ,
thin=1 ,
```

all traces look good enough and no more autocorrelation, even if $\beta \gg 1$.

Example:
[image]
[image]

A result:
[image]
[image]